# Unexpected Difficulties with "Hello, World!"

Tags: emacs, clojure, compiler-errors, leiningen

I would like to learn Clojure and I've downloaded and set up the following gizmos:

- Clojure 1.6.0 from official site;
- Leiningen 2.4.3;
- Cider 0.6.0 from GitHub.

I've got it working. Now I'm trying to print message `"Hello, World!"`, while running Cider from within Emacs:

```
; CIDER 0.6.0 (Java 1.7.0_65, Clojure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.0-beta5)
user> (println "Hello World!")
Hello World!NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I
clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630
(session.clj:43)NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I
clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)
user>
```

What is this noise all about? When I just run:

```
$ clojure
;Clojure 1.6.0
user=> (println "Hello, World!")
Hello, World!
nil
```

everything is fine. When I do it with Leiningen:

```
$ lein repl
; lotsa stuff here...
user=> (println "Hello, World!")
```

After entering of this command I relish the following poetry:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: rprintln in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1) NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)
Exception in thread "nREPL-worker-3" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session$session_out$fn__7630.doInvoke(session.clj:43)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:460)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session.proxy$java.io.Writer$ff19274a.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
    at clojure.core$fn__5471.invoke(core_print.clj:191)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)
    at clojure.core$pr_on.invoke(core.clj:3392)
    at clojure.core$pr.invoke(core.clj:3404)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$prn.doInvoke(core.clj:3437)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$println.doInvoke(core.clj:3457)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.main$repl_caught.invoke(main.clj:158)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569$fn__7582.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:76)
    at clojure.main$repl$fn__6634.invoke(main.clj:259)
    at clojure.main$repl.doInvoke(main.clj:257)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1096)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:56)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1862)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:41)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__7610$fn__7613.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:171)
    at clojure.core$comp$fn__4192.invoke(core.clj:2402)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__7603.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:138)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Oh, Nooo. What a pain! Stop it, stop it!

---

I'm so perplexed. What is it and how do I fix this? Has anyone similar experience? How do I print `"Hello, World!"` in Clojure?

Comment: +1 for "I relish the following poetry"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce this error with leinengen 2.4.3. You can run `lein upgrade 2.4.2` to get the most recent version that actually works. It's unusual for the leiningen team to mark a bad build like this as stable, at first I suspected cider. By the way, the "stable" version of cider should be 0.7.0.

Comment: As a long term Clojure user, I find this really disappointing, in general I have found the tooling, `lein` in particular, to be one of the best things about Clojure, and I hope the stability gets back on track. Also this error only comes up if you run `lein` without a project directory (you can create a project using `lein create foo` for a project named foo).

Comment: About cider: indeed, 0.7.0 is latest version, but it's [easy to miss it](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/releases).

Comment: 0.8.0 is the latest, 0.7.0 is the only one ever targeted to be stable

Comment: and I don't blame you for getting a wrong version with cider, or any unexpected cider related behavior, it is a permanently bleeding edge tool, usually broken, from all evidence I have seen

Comment: Usually broken? Wild claims like this one infuriate me - while there are breakages on the master branch from time to time, they have always been addressed promptly and tagged releases are reasonably stable.

Comment: Bozhidar: in fairness, the issue could be my own emacs config? I have tried various versions, and ended up sticking with 0.6 because I got constant errors and misbehavior with other versions. I am aware that my own laziness / impatience is partially to blame, as I don't want to spend hours tracking down problems in my emacs setup. All of that said, after decades of emacs usage, I have not seen another package that people had so much trouble with. Perhaps the setup and upgrade process have too many places for user error to occur? Or I, and many of the people I help, are too dumb to use cider.